# What Is The Non-Extra Equivalent Of Coends?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

As far as I understand, the coend of a diagram $X:I^\text{op}\times I\to D$ is an object $x\in D_0$ together with a natural isomorphism $\alpha:[[I,D]](X,\Delta^e_*)\cong D(x,*)$ in $[D,\text{Set}]$ where I denote with $[[I,D]]$ the category of diagrams $I^\text{op}\times I\to D$ and extranatural transformations between them as well as with $\Delta^e_*:D\to[[I,D]]$ the functor taking an object $y$ to the constant diagram $(i_0,i_1)\mapsto y$.

I feel now a bit stupid because I cannot tell what the analogous concept for natural transformations is called.  I'm sure I have already seen it but, given $X:I\to D$, what exactly is an object $x\in D_0$ together with a natural transformation $\alpha:[I,D](X,\Delta_*)\cong D(x,*)$?

Also, what about the notion $\int^i X(i,i)$?  The coend does not only depend on the $X(i,i)$ values, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've written in the first paragraph. For $[[I,D]](X,\Delta^e_*)$ to make sense $\Delta^e_*$ should be a functor $I^{op}\times I\to D$, but you seem to say it's something else. And I've never heard the phrase "constant extranatural transformation" before and am not sure what you mean by it.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine $[[I,D]](X,\Delta^e_*)$ should be a functor $D\to\text{Set}$ via $y\mapsto[[I,D]](X,\Delta^e_y)$, $\Delta^e_y$, does that make sense?  I wrote 'constant extranatural transformation' which makes no sense, fixed it now.

Comment: Also I meant $D\to[[I,D]]$, not $D\to[[I\to D]]$, fixed it now.

Comment: Got confused with extranatural transformations and diagrams.  Fixed some more things, hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case for ordinary natural transformations is just that of a colimit. The natural isomorphism $[I,D](X,\Delta_*)\simeq D(x,*)$ says that there is a natural correspondence between morphisms $x\to y$ for any $y$, and cocones under $X$ with vertex $y$ (cocones are just natural transformations to constant functors); and this is just what it means to be a colimit.

And what's important in the notation $\int^iX(i,i)$ is that it *binds* those variable positions--it is *not* saying that it is only constructed from the "diagonal" values. It can be important to be clear on what variables you're binding because it might happen that you have a diagram $F:C\times C^{op}\times C\to D$ and can form the coend $\int^cF(c,c,c')$ or $\int^cF(c',c,c)$ for a given parameter $c'$, and there's no reason these will be the same things; the notation tells you which two arguments you're taking the coend with respect to.

Comment: It's also true that the coend is a quotient of $\coprod X(i,i)$, so the notation captures the sort of "generating" objects fully.